# How to make dictionary entry a pandas dataframe by specifying columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
mydict ={'9788845278518': [['/book/show/24235201-numero-zero', 'Italian'], ['/book/show/10522.Il_nome_della_rosa', 'Italian']]}
```

And I would like to make it a dataframe like this:

```
ISBN, LINK, LANG
9788845278518, /book/show/24235201-numero-zero, Italian
9788845278518, /book/show/10522.Il_nome_della_rosa, Italian
```

So I tried by doing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict)
```

And I wanted to use `df.explode` and then doing `transpose`, but it didn't really work because my column is not named. Also, there must be a simpler way to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a `defaultdict` before creating a `Dataframe`, since `pandas` operations are usually more expensive:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

mydict ={'9788845278518': [['/book/show/24235201-numero-zero', 'Italian'], ['/book/show/10522.Il_nome_della_rosa', 'Italian']]}

d = defaultdict(list)
for key,value in mydict.items():
  for v in value:
    d.setdefault('ISBN', []).append(key) 
    d.setdefault('LINK', []).append(v[0])
    d.setdefault('LANG', []).append(v[1])    

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(d))
print(df)
```

```
            ISBN                                 LINK     LANG
0  9788845278518      /book/show/24235201-numero-zero  Italian
1  9788845278518  /book/show/10522.Il_nome_della_rosa  Italian
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict)
df = pd.melt(df, var_name='ISBN', value_name='value')
df[['LINK', 'LANG']] = df['value'].apply(pd.Series)
df.drop(columns='value')
```

`melt` to move column names to the new `ISBN` column, and explode the lists into the two new columns `LINK`, `LANG`

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the dictionary using list comprehension then create a new dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(k, *l) for k, v in mydict.items() for l in v], 
    columns=['ISBN', "LINK", 'LANG']
)
```

---

```
print(df)
            ISBN                                 LINK     LANG
0  9788845278518      /book/show/24235201-numero-zero  Italian
1  9788845278518  /book/show/10522.Il_nome_della_rosa  Italian
```